# cloud functions for firebase onwrite not triggering any executions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.editData = functions.database.ref('/AllData/hello/A').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const after = change.after;
    if (after.exists()) {
        const data = after.val();
        var value = data;
        // set of data to multiply by turns ratio
        var actualEIn = (value.ein)*200;
        console.log('Data Edited');
    }
    return admin.database().ref('/editedData/hello/A').push({
        ein: actualEIn,
    });
});
```

Edit: made some edits to the code as suggested! However, when I deploy it there are literally no logs.
[image: No logs]

Comment: update: i added a /{id} behind A and got this error code: TypeError: snapshot.val is not a function
    at exports.editValues.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:17:27)

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
exports.editValues = functions.database.ref('/AllData/hello/A').onWrite((snapshot) => {
const data = snapshot.val();
if (data.exists()) {
```

into this:

```
exports.editValues = functions.database.ref('/AllData/hello/A').onWrite((change,context) => {
const data = change.after.val();
if (data.exists()) {
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database

Comment: This won't help because raw javascript objects returned by `val()` won't have an `exists()` method on them.  Please read my answer for more details.

Comment: Hi thank you that worked! However, it only worked for the first part of the code before 'return'. At return I'm supposed to get another branch of data coming out but it isn't! is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.editData = functions.database.ref('/AllData/hello/A/{id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const afterData = change.after;
    if (afterData.exists()) {
        console.log('hey');
        const data = afterData.val();
        // set of data to multiply by turns ratio
        var actualEIn = (data.ein)*200;
    }
    return admin.database().ref('/editedData/hello/A').push({
        ein: actualEIn,
    });
});
```

Hi guys thank you for all your help! :) I managed to solve this by adding a /{id} at the back!

Answer (score 0):

You've got two things wrong here.

First, newer versions of the firebase-functions SDK since version 1.0 deliver a [`Change`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) object to onWrite handlers instead of a snapshot, as it appears you are expecting.  The Change object has properties for `before` and `after` with [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot) objects of the contents of the database before and after the change that triggered the function.  [Please read the documentation for database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to get all the information.

Second, [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#exists) is a method on [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot), but you're using it on the raw JavaScript object value of the contents of the database the location of change.  JavaScript objects coming from `val()` will not have any methods to call.

You should probably update your code to:

1. Use the latest version of the firebase-functions module
2. Alter your function to accept the Change object instead of a snapshot
3. Use the exists() method on a snapshot in the change, rather than a raw JavaScript object.

Starter code:

```
exports.editValues = functions.database.ref('/AllData/hello/A').onWrite((change) => {
    const after = change.after;  // the DataSnapshot of the data after it was changed
    if (after.exists()) {
        const data = after.val()  // the raw JavaScript value of the location
        // use data here
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, sorry this still didn't work! Am still unable to get the function to run!

Comment: i managed to deploy the function but it is still not reading data from database and then changing it

Comment: Is there an error? Are you logging anything? What is it doing instead?

Comment: on firebase cloud functions' end, there is no error. Data has been coming in every 20s but still no new folder of editedData created

Comment: it's literally doing nothing haha. In the logs there is nothing

Comment: If you're logging at the very beginning of the function before anything happen, but nothing appears in the log, that means your function isn't registered at the location of the change.  Please edit your question to describe in detail how the database is being updated (show code), and why you expect your function to trigger.

Comment: log at the very beginning of the function to know if the trigger is actually executing.  Also show how you're writing to the database in such a way that expects the code to trigger.

Comment: after adding a /{ein} to /A, i managed to log some error in firebase cloud functions. TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined <- the error